# How to import and process all files from a blob storage container to azure databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-blob-storage

I'm working with azure databricks and blob storage. I have a storage account that stores data from IOT devices for every hour. so the folder structure is 
   **{year/month/day/hour}** it stores data as **csv** files. My requirement is, need to access the files from azure databricks daily basis (so there will be 24 folders starting from 0-23) and need to perform some calculations.

Comment: See if this [link](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) helps?

Comment: Which language are using scala, python ??

Comment: I'm using python.

Answer (score 2):

In order to process many files under a wasb container you'll need to use the Hadoop Input Format glob patterns.  The patterns are as follow, somewhat similar to regex:

```
* (match 0 or more character)
? (match single character)
[ab] (character class)
[^ab] (negated character class)
[a-b] (character range)
{a,b} (alternation)
\c (escape character)
```

For your use case, the following should work:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("/container/*/*/*/*.csv")
```